# How to create a user with vtwsclib?

Tags: php, api, web-services, vtiger

I'm using: https://github.com/salaros/vtwsclib-php

In github there are examples to create leads but I would like to have an example to create users, I am trying and it gives me the following error:

> string(115) "{"success":false,"error":{"code":"ACCESS_DENIED","message":"Permission to perform the operation is denied for id"}}"

EDIT

php file i run:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Salaros\Vtiger\VTWSCLib\WSClient;
$client = new WSClient('http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX/', 'admin', 'XXXXXX');

$moduleName = 'Users';
$sp=$client->entities->doCreate($moduleName, Array('user_name'=> 'teste1',
'user_password'=>'teste1',
'email1'=>'teste1@gmail.com',
'confirm_password'=>'teste1',
'last_name'=>'lastname',
'status'=>'Active',
'roleid'=>'H37'));
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you used? If you share more about your problem it's easier to help you.

Comment: @JanisJansen I have edited with the file that I run, if you want me to also upload the code with the functions performed by / salaros / vtwsclib-php
Tell me, thanks.